# Which indices should be added to speed up queries on massive InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `letters` (
  `a` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `b` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `c` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `d` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `e` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

- The table will have about 1+ billion rows.
- Each column can be queried; each column can be referenced. e.g.:

  - SELECT [any column] FROM letters WHERE [any / any other column] IN ([subquery or list]);

My question: what indices should I add to speed up any query in the format above? (Also, if possible, please try to describe 'why' it/they should be added so that I can learn from your answer).

Thanks!

-- Extra info: inserts will happen on a fairly regular basis (a few/handful every second) but select queries will happen more frequently.

Comment: You've really provided nothing to go on without being specific about your common queries.

Comment: Rather than list out every single query possibility, I provided the template of all queries. Assume that each column can go in each blank. This is why I am asking the question, it isn't a simple: use this index because your queries lean toward it. -- There are no 'common queries'. It is an even distribution of the listed template.

Comment: Very important thing you have to consider is selectivity of the index, i.e. how many distinct values each of your column will contain (compared to the total number of rows).

Comment: @a1ex07 - 'a' will be unique. b-d will likely have total rows / 1,000,000 unique values. 'e' will have about 15 unique values.

Comment: You could partition the table by column 'e' and then set up indexes for b-d

Comment: Are your permutation of queries *really* that many? Anyone who queries this table with a filter on e would need shooting because it isn't selective enough.

Comment: 'e' will be plenty selective. Likely there will be 50,000 rows where 'e' equals one value and 2 rows where it equals another. The query would be looking for the 2 other values. You can think of 'e' like how outdated a row is. Most queries will be looking for the smallest value of 'e', which will be a very small number of rows.

Comment: I quote "'e' will have about 15 unique values." that is 66 million rows per value

Comment: @TomMac - Interesting idea. How would it affect speed if the query didn't involve 'e'? Wouldn't it still have to search every partition (and now it has to go through the effort of combining/searching each partitions)?

Comment: @gbn I didn't state the distribution of the values, just the count of unique values.

Comment: Doesn't matter. WHERE e = 1 is about selectivity, not distribution of e values over other column permutations. If you did WHERE a=42 and e=1 then yes, it matters.

Comment: If a query did not involve a predicate on 'e' then, yes, there would most likely be some extra overhead in merging results from multiple partitions. Ideally, partitioning (and there is nothing to stop you from partitioning on any of the other columns BTW) should be based on the most used predicate column (where a=, where b=, where c= etc etc). Another thing you could look at is whether you actually need all the data. Can any of it be archived to keep data volumes down & hence speed up any queries run? Good luck!

Comment: @TomMac I actually hadn't thought about partitioning.. but now that you've explained it I think a LIST partition might be a good idea (and I won't have to index it as well.. I can just index the other columns). -- I'm pretty certain that none of the data can be archived. -- How would partitioning the other columns help? Wouldn't their high selectivity index reduce the helpfulness of partitioning because the server would still have to search all of the partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any column can appear in the WHERE clause, you've to add an index for each of the column, except for the field **a** since is already the PRIMARY KEY and as such is already indexed.

**UPDATE**: as for the subsequent discussion, Poodlehat pointed out that the column **e** has a low index selectivity, i.e. "The ratio of the number of distinct values in the indexed column / columns to the number of records in the table". For this reason, it's not clear whether adding an index on column **e** will help or slow down queries. So Lucas will try experimentally and hopefully share the results to us.

Comment: This is what I thinking should be done, but will having one index on each column be all that much faster than no indices (other than PK)? I know I shouldn't add compound indices for each 2-pair because then my inserts would take forever.

Comment: Bad idea to add an index on columns with poor selectvity.

Comment: You're right, but, assuming that the 15 values of column e are uniformedly distributed, it means 6,66% - On this [document about Oracle](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.html), but is a general guideline, it says: we should create indexes on tables that are often queried for less than 15% of the table's rows.

Comment: @stivlo - Unfortunately you can't assume a uniform distribution. Likely there will be cases where one value of 'e' will result in 20% of the results, another 15%, another 10%, and the rest.. smaller %.

Comment: @Lucas, yes is possible, so maybe he could try with and without the index on column **e** and see which works faster.

Comment: @stivlo - 'he' being me? :) Probably a good idea to try it with and without the index on 'e'.

Comment: @Lucas, yes, you, I got confused with the usernames, sorry :-)

Comment: I believe I am going to go with @TomMac's suggestion (in the question comments) and list partition based on column e.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a unique index on `a` (or it should be a primary key), definitely indexes on `b,c,d` (on each). No need for index on `e` (it won't be used anyway since as you say it has just 15 different values)